# Input volume of spark job using cmd

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, google-cloud-platform, bigdata, data-processing

Is there a way to check, how much volume of data is being read by a spark job using code.

My intention is to find how much data we are processing daily , at job level.

Comment: using cmd or code?

Comment: Thanks for replying @MajidHajibaba anything is fine, i need to create daily usage report.